# Moodle Encryption used MD5 earlier. Which technique it uses now?

Tags: moodle

I am using Moodle 2.8.3+ (Build: 20150305) and want to know which password encryption technique does it use.

The older versions uses MD5 encryption techniques but this is not working with this new version.

Is there a way to get the encryption technique or does anybody know it readily?

Answer (score 2):

Moodle passwords are not encrypted, they are hashed (an important distinction as encrypted passwords can be decrypted, whereas hashing is a one-way process).

If you take a look inside the 'hash_internal_user_password' function (https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/lib/moodlelib.php#L4743) you will find that it calls the standard PHP function [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

The documentation for that function states that it uses the bcrypt algorithm.

Comment: Then what should I do if I want to authenticate one of the users from my Android application?

Comment: When we create users in moodle.. and save password for them... same password has different hash created and stored in the database.. so from where does the moodle site authenticates users ? and creates the similar hash ?

Comment: There must be some way that your android application is communicating with the Moodle server. If you are doing this by directly inserting values into the database backend, then this sounds like the wrong approach. A better approach would be to implement some sort of web service that could use the standard Moodle API to create the users (or even a CLI script that could do this and be called from your server-side application).

Comment: I dont have to create users.. I just want to access one of the passwords which I guess is in Blowfish algorithm for hashing. Now I am facing problem for user authentication there.